# How to insert PersonEmail and PersonMobile fields in related record lightning component on a case record?

Tags: lightning, person-accounts

The Actions in Account does not let me choose Person Acc fields but the requirement is to add PersonEmail and PersonMobile.. how do I add that in the update action?